# Target [App\Service\InvitationServiceInterface] is not instantiable?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have service provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class InvitationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Service\InvitationServiceInterface', 'App\Service\InvitationService');
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Also there is an custom interface `InvitationServiceInterface` and `InvitationService`:

```
<?php
namespace App\Service;

class InvitationService implements InvitationServiceInterface
{
    public function doAwesomeThing()
    {
        echo 'Do...';
    }
}
```

Interface is:

```
<?php
namespace App\Service;

interface InvitationServiceInterface
{
    public function doAwesomeThing();
}
```

These both files are place in path:

```
App\Service\InvitationServiceInterface
App\Service\InvitationService
```

So, I get an error:

> Illuminate \ Contracts \ Container \ BindingResolutionException Target
>   [App\Service\InvitationServiceInterface] is not instantiable.

**Using is:**

```
use App\Service\InvitationServiceInterface;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PassportController extends Controller
{

    public function register(Request $request, InvitationServiceInterface $invitationService)
    {
}
```

Comment: Are you manually calling `register` or is it a route endpoint? Are there any parameters on the route?

Comment: Yes, I manually call `register` it has no parameters: `Route::post('register', 'PassportController@register');`

Comment: What happens if you instead call `resolve('App\Service\InvitationServiceInterface')`? If this also doesn't work then double-check that the service provider is actually getting called, e.g. by adding a `dd()`.

Comment: Call this `resolve('App\Service\InvitationServiceInterface')` in controller?

Comment: The same result, when I use `resolve`

Comment: Yes, and remove the parameter.

Comment: The same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the laravel service container in the `constructor` of a **controller**, i.e.:

```
class PassportController extends Controller
{
    public function _construct(InvitationServiceInterface $invitationService)
    {
        $this->invitationService = $invitationService;
    }
}
```

But not in a **route controller function** like you tried because here is the area of the `route model binding` so the service container is trying to instanciate a route model.

Comment: I tried it return null `dd($this->invitationService);`

Comment: try to add `use App\Service\InvitationService` and BTW I removed the exception and answered your question, probably you have some other errors in your code

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer as it solves the error posted.

Comment: It removes the exception or not?

Comment: I would dissagree in laravel `"laravel/framework": "v6.20.16"` you can pass dependency right in method of a controller not only in constractor.

Comment: @112Legion I would disagree too, but the question has the laravel-5 tag.

Answer (score 0):

Probably service provider was cached.

Try to delete those two files:

[image]

Or run
`php artisan config:clear`

Or delete them derectry

```
rm bootstrap/cache/packages.php
rm bootstrap/cache/services.php
```